# I’m trying to add a new field in Syteline

Tags: erp

I’m trying to add a new field in syteline called customer rank in an existing customer form.

I understand how to create the field in the form but I would need steps on how to create a new form for that new field. This form is where the data for the field can be updated.

Is there an order to follow, I.e.

Create new form called Customer Rank

Create a SQL table

Create the new field

I haven’t found any documentation on this online and tried creating the field, but the data would need to the linked to a new form. Then this new field should  e added and appear in the SQL table for that existing form.

Answer (score 0):

## Background

You need to create a UET User Field, then a UET Class. Then link the UET Class to the table (customer_mst in this case), and then link the UET User Field to the UET Class. Lastly, use the UET Impact Schema form, which creates the custom SQL column to the SQL table from your UET definitions.

Once you do that, you can either add it directly to the form via the a pseudo-property that the form sees, or you can extend the IDO (SLCustomers in this case) and add a property.

## Example

#### UET User Field:

- User Field Name: `Uf_Customers_Rank`
- User Data Type: `ShortDescType`

#### UET Class:

- Class Name: `[PREFIX]_Customers` (change [PREFIX] to a three digit prefix, based on your company name)

#### Extended IDO

- IDO Name: `ue_[PREFIX]_SLCustomers`
- Extends: `SLCustomers`
- Replace: `True`

#### IDO Property

- Property Name: `ue_Rank`
- Property Type: `Bound`
- SQL Binding: `cus.Uf_Customers_Rank`
- Property Class: `ShortDesc`

Answer (score -1):

I believe the correct order would be to create the SQL table, the IDO to reference the table, then the form to call on the IDO.